Jmeter Selenium Plugin - Could not start a new session
I want to use Selenium samplers in my Jmeter tests. However, I ran into a puzzling issue whereby the browser refuses to start. I place jp@gc - Edge Driver Config in my thread group
at the top of the tree and provide the path the the driver, like so:
C:\Users\MyApps\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe
path to edgedriver in jmeter
Then I provide a basic webdriver sampler and I start the test. Immediately encounter the following error:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'H50707', ip: '172.25.128.246'
Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --start-maximized], extensions: []}, proxy: Proxy(system)}]}]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:163) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:108) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:60) ~[selenium-edge-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:56) ~[selenium-edge-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.EdgeDriverConfig.createBrowser(EdgeDriverConfig.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.EdgeDriverConfig.createBrowser(EdgeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:223) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:154) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:802) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1029) [jorphan.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:1012) [jorphan.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:770) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:758) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(java.lang.Throwable)'
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:188) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
... 16 more

I get similar results when I use any other webdriver, be it chrome or firefox. Obviously the webdriver version I use corresponds to the version  of the browser installed in the system (so it is version 128.0.2739.79 of Edge Driver and browser in my system).
I cannot figure this out. The only thing that comes to my mind that Jmeter Selenium plugin is for some reason not compatible with the latest versions of browsers. However, I cannot find any compatibility matrix on the Internet. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Please find attached the jmeter.log file

We cannot guess the reason without seeing the

full error stacktrace, the most interesting is caused by section
jmeter.log file (preferably with JMeter debug logging enabled)
edgedriver log file (preferably with debug logging enabled)


Thank you for your comment. Today I performed clean install of Jmeter and all the plugins (for the 3rd time!), but this time I was able to launch the browser. My conclusion is that somehow, someway, the Plugin Manager did not install Selenium plugin correctly the first 3 times I did it.
FYI, I added more complete logs in my post, but I think the whole thread may be closed.
